# Why to use -f in docker build command

Tags: docker, docker-build

I follow [this K8s tutorial](https://www.linux.com/blog/learn/chapter/Intro-to-Kubernetes/2017/5/set-cicd-pipeline-kubernetes-part-1-overview), and in the middle of the file, there is the following instruction:

```
12. Now let’s build an image, giving it a special name that points to our local cluster registry.

$docker build -t 127.0.0.1:30400/hello-kenzan:latest -f applications/hello-kenzan/Dockerfile applications/hello-kenzan
```

I don't understand why do you need to point to the dockerfile using `-f applications/hello-kenzan/Dockerfile`.

In the man of docker build:

```
-f, --file=PATH/Dockerfile
          Path to the Dockerfile to use. If the path is a relative path and you are
          building from a local directory, then the path must be relative to that
          directory. If you are building from a remote URL pointing to either a
          tarball or a Git repository, then the path must be relative to the root of
          the remote context. In all cases, the file must be within the build context.
          The default is Dockerfile.
```

So -f is to point to the dockerfile, but we already gave the path of the dockerfile in the end of build command - `docker build ...applications/hello-kenzan`, so why do you need to write it twice? am I missing something?

Comment: can you check if you really need to put `applications/hello-kenzan` at the end?

Comment: I do . Without it I get ""docker build" requires exactly 1 argument.". But it seems like I don't need the -f.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this is because he probably had multiple files called `Dockerfile` and using -f tells the docker to NOT use the Dockerfile in the current directory (when there's one) but use the Dockerfile in the `applications/hello-kenzan` instead.

While in THIS PARTICULAR example it was unnecessary to do this, I appreciate the tutorial creator to show you an option to use PATH and point the -f at specific place to show you (the person who wants to learn) that it is possible to use Dockerfiles that are not in PATH (i.e when you have multiple dockerfiles you want to create your builds with or when the file is not named `Dockerfile` but e.g `myapp-dockerfile`)

Comment: Docker looks for a Dockerfile (named 'Dockerfile') in the given PATH (`applications/hello-kenzan` in this case) by default - not in the directory where the `docker build` command is executed. So the usage of `-f` is superfluous in this case.

Comment: So the conclusion is that its redundant?

Comment: yes I updated my answer on why I see this a good tutorial example, though.

Comment: You can call your Dockerfiles however you want. if you have the PATH `applications/hello-kenzan` and that path contains a file called Dockerfile (as in your case) then you don't have to use `-f`. If you rename your Dockerfile to e.g. "testfile" then you have to use `docker build -f applications/hello-kenzan/testfile applications/hello-kenzan`

Answer (score 1):

You are right. In this case you don't have to use the `-f` option. The [official docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/) say:

-f: Name of the Dockerfile (Default is ‘PATH/Dockerfile’) and as the given PATH is `applications/hello-kenzan` the Dockerfile there will be found implicitly.